# cannot ping http://localhost:3000 with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot ping http://localhost:3000 from my terminal with Webrick running.
However, when loading it on a web browser I get the default "Welcome abroad" page.
I'm using Rails as a backend service for a mobile app - so I need to access the API this way.

```
>ping http://localhost:3000/
ping: cannot resolve http://localhost:3000/: Unknown host
>ping http://127.0.0.1
ping: cannot resolve http://127.0.0.1: Unknown host
>ping http://127.0.0.1:3000
ping: cannot resolve http://127.0.0.1:3000: Unknown host
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ping` command sends ICMP packets and has no idea what a URL is, it [pre-dates the web by about ten years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)#History). It wants a hostname, like:

```
ping localhost
```

What you want is to use a web tool like `curl` or `wget` to access your page:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/
```